# How do I identify ICD9 Codes as dummy variables?

Tags: python, dummy-variable

I am attempting to convert from STATA to python and am recreating some of my previous work/code in python. I have a dataset with 5 variables, 1 patient ID numbers and 4 ICD-9 external injury codes (known as e-codes)

I want to create a variable which identifies people as being fallers versus non-fallers, identified with Ecodes 880.XX-889.xx.

I want a variable which indicates if a patient had a code E880.xx-E889.xx in ANY of the 4 ecode variables (value of 1), if they don't have a E880.xx-E889.xx code give them a value of 0, but don't give them a value (coded as missing) if the 4 e-code values are missing, since they didn't have an external injury.

In STATA the code is pretty straght forward:
gen fall_inj_ecode=0

```
foreach var in ecode1 ecode2 ecode3 ecode4{  
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E880")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E881")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E882")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E883")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E884")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E885")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E886")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E887")>0
replace fall_inj_ecode=1 if strpos(`var', "E888")>0
```

note that there are subcodes (hence the ".xx" part) which are coded without the period. So a code of E8801 is considered between 880.xx and 889.xx and denotes a fall injury.

Fortuanately for STATA, if the ecode values are missing or empty, it automatically fills marks the new variable as missing, I'm not sure if this is the case for python. Unfortunately, this is where I get stuck. after scouring the web I can't seem to find any examples of equivalent code for python. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide an example (in Python) of what the data looks like at the start? Is it a list, a combined string, a dict? Also, can you show how you'd like to use the result in code? In general, it is good to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of what you've tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, the title of your question seems overly specific, since you really seem to be asking "how to detect if any of a number of substrings occurs in a number of strings?", 'ICD9' has little to do with the technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your data could be in a number of different forms, the basic problem is the same, but the implementation will vary depending on what your data looks like.

Here's a working example for an assumed data format:

```
faller_codes = ['E880', 'E881', 'E882', 'E883', 'E884', 'E885', 'E886', 'E887', 'E888']
patients = [
    (1, ['example E2345', 'example E8801', 'E884 example', 'E799, E880, E8881']),
    (2, ['example E2345', 'example E8891', 'E9880 example', ''])
]

faller_patients = [
    n for n, codes in patients
    if any([
        any([
            faller_code in code
            for faller_code in faller_codes
        ]) for code in codes
    ])
]

print(faller_patients)
```

After running, `faller_patients` contains only the ids of 'faller' patients.